# Reset mysql database before running a JUnit test

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring, junit

I have around 10 JUnit that will be executed automatically. I would like to reset the database in every of them. I have this piece of code:

```
//@Transactional
public class TestMediaObjectService extends AbstractDataAccessTest{

//This method reset the database, emptying the tables
    @Test
    public void testCreateDataBase() throws Exception {
        TestDatabaseCreation creation = new TestDatabaseCreation();
        creation.resetDatabase();
    }

//This is one of the methods. 
    @Test
    public void testStoreMediaObject() throws Exception {
//......
}
```

When I reset the database manually with the same script that I am using in the method `testCreateDataBase` and after that run this test (without that method), the tables are created automatically. But if I run the code as I have pasted above, that tables are not created, therefore I get this error:

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'one_table' doesn't exist

How could I run that method in every before running other methods in the test? The annotation `@Transactional` was removed, but error was still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you don't need to reset the database manually, because JUNIT does this for you before every test. Use these annotations:

```
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

Junit will rollback all transactions done in a test after running it. All you need is an existing empty database. If you use hibernate to manage your entities, you don't even need to have the tables.

If you want to do it manually, use the `@Before` annotation at a setup method:

```
@Before
public void init() {
    createTables();
}
```

This will be run before every test.

If you want to setup your database tables once for all tests in a class, use `@BeforeClass`. But usually that's not best practice, as every test should be independent of any other test.

Comment: This configuration doesn't reset database. It says that test will be executed in a db transaction and transaction won't be commited but rolled-back. Everything will happen in entity manager cache or not commited DB transaction. Simple unit test should work this way. More complex integration tests won't.

Comment: I see your point, even though the question was not specific about whether data actually needs to be committed. But: Why would you want to actually commit data to the database in a unit test anyway? The only reasons I can think of is testing your database connection or transaction environment or if you have a distributed environment. Aparpt from that integration tests on existing data shouldn't be done in a unit test I think as that test would not be independent. It should rather setup all the required data itself.

Comment: thanks, but the database is not reset with these annotations. I get DuplicateObjectException. I am making some test in my application, and I have a database for that issue. Is not the database to be used in the applicaction itself

Comment: @Blanca Hdez: "but the database is not reset with these annotations. I get DuplicateObjectException" .. It is correct, this annotations do NOT RESET the Database, instead they prevent the changes made in the Test to be persisted (except you open a new transaction in the test). So may the problem is that you should start with an empty database.